# nginx directory authentication leads to 403 forbidden despite correct credentials

Tags: authentication, nginx

I have a wordpress website. I want to make some files available only via a username/password authentication. For this I simply want to use the nginx authentication. So I did the following steps.

1) Create a `.htpasswd` file with an encrypted password for user `asdf`: `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd asdf`

I am then prompted to enter and re-enter the password. The file is created and has the following permission rights:

> -rw-r--r--   1 root root   43 Jan 26 13:39 .htpasswd

2) I change the nginx configuration by adding the following block:

```
    location /targetfolder/pdf {
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```

`/targetfolder/pdf` is the location where the files reside that should be password protected.

3) I then restart nginx: `sudo service nginx restart`.

Then I browse to the folder and am prompted for the credentials. After entering the correct credentials I get an 403 forbidden nginx error message.

The error in error.log says:

> 2020/01/26 13:45:21 [error] 29853#0: *3 directory index of "/var/www//targetfolder/pdf/" is forbidden, client: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /targetfolder/pdf/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

What am I doing wrong? I have already tried different solutions such a trying different locations for `.htpasswd`, setting the [index-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16510374/403-forbidden-nginx-using-correct-credentials#comment23702894_16510516) in the nginx-configuration etc. Could it have something to do with wordpress? Could it be that something goes wrong when encrypting/decrypting the entered password?

FWIW, nginx is running with the root user. the command `ps aux | grep nginx` returns.

> root     29849  0.0  0.1  91836  3060 ?        Ss   13:44   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;

Answer (score 0):

Can answer my own question. The configuration basically was correct, however, the following line in the error.log indicated my error:

> 2020/01/26 14:56:13 [error] 30373#0: *54 directory index of "/targetfolder/pdf/" is forbidden, client: 80.110.88.251, server: example.com, request: "GET /pdf/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"

This means that per default nginx seems not to allow directory listings (which is a good thing). So I just had to set Autoindex on for my targetfolder resulting in the following configuration of the site/location:

```
    location /targetfolder/pdf {
            autoindex on; #added
            auth_basic "Restricted Content";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
```